# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed - Form Tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms (same problem with MVC) project that I'm trying to use to host simple JavaScript exercises with an HTML form that I have added.

Similar questions on this topic have not led me to a solution. I'm guessing I have to add a special handler in IIS for a HTML page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <form method="post" action="/test/tasks.html" id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Enter an item to be done.
            </legend>
            <div>
                <label for="task">Task</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="task" id="task" required="required" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add it!" id="submit">
            <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/tasks.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to POST to a HTML page? Or is `/test/tasks.html` a web-service with a .html extension? I think you are going to need to add some more detail about what exactly you are trying to do...

Comment: Yes, posting to an HTML page. Test is the name of the project and test.html is at root level (not in a folder).

Comment: You normally *can't* do an HTTP POST [method] to an HTML page, they don't do any processing - they are usually just static resources.  You would normally post to an ASP page (or some other variety of page with server side processing enabled).  The fact that the server is telling you "you can't do this" would suggest that this is the issue.

Comment: I took JS classes online few weeks ago and we were using HTML forms and JS scripts in MVC projects. This were online VMs. What am I missing?

Comment: If you're not actually expecting a meaningful response try changing the method to "get" (i.e. `<form method="get" ...`)

Comment: I'm trying to generate response in the output div using JS.

Comment: *Normally*, the server generates the response - there won't be any JS involved in this process.  You can modify the page using JS (on the client/browser) easily, but it usually won't involve a round trip to the server (i.e. a form `submit`), except if you're getting data with Ajax (or similar).  Methinks you're missing some fundamentals.

Comment: Tibrogargan, that helped me solve it! I changed form tag action attribute to action="#". Please feel free to to present this as an answer and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to handle forms that have nowhere to submit (like yours) is simply to not have a submit button (which are almost just a button that calls `form.submit()`). Things to pay attention to:

- Set the "type" of your button element to "button" (the default is "submit").
- Don't use `onclick="foo()"`.  In order to preserve separation between form and function, add click handlers through addEventListener (or equivalent)
- Don't try and modify the DOM until after all the content is loaded, it doesn't exist yet.
- Using javascript DOM methods to create DOM elements is counter-intuitively inefficient, just add on extra HTML if you can.

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Foo</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";

var javascript_DOM_methods_are_efficient = false;

function displayResult() {
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    if (javascript_DOM_methods_are_efficient) {
        results.append(document.createTextNode("extraordinary"));
        results.append(document.createElement('br'));
    } else {
        results.innerHTML += "extraordinary<br />";
    }
}

function init() {
    document.getElementById("eric").addEventListener( "click", displayResult, false );
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
</script>
<body>
    <form name="form">
        <button type="button" id="eric">half a button</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great answer, but could you expand on the subtlety of input type of 'submit' vs 'button'?

Comment: Can't get this to work: document.addEventListener("DOMLoaded", init, false);
Had to use window.onload = init; instead.

Comment: Sorry, didn't include IE specific JavaScript.

Comment: Check out [this answer](/a/469084/2487517) for differences between `button` and `input type="button"/"submit"`